# How to search for project files on Eclipse?

Tags: editor, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse Mars CDT. If we need to open a specific source file in a project with hundreds of source files it becomes a daunting task to scroll through the source files and visually select the desired. Instead, it would be nice if we can do a search on the *Project Explorer* window. Is there a built in feature on Eclipse or are there any Eclipse plugins which I could use for this purpose?

EDIT:
The question is targeted towards ease of use. The Search window does not provide a solution as it performs a text search and provides a list of occurrences of the search text which needs to be scrolled and searched again (if a wildcard is used or if there are many occurrences of the class name in the source). What I'm after is something similar to the 'Search Solution Explorer' (in the image below) option in Visual Studio IDE. Which will enable me to click on the *Project Explorer Search* and start typing where it narrows down the matching files in the *Project Explorer View*.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-84b.htm)

There you go, from the eclipse help. You just have to hit the `search` button.

EDIT:

Just searched around a bit and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3479958/7008354). So you are able to search for filenames using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and for classnames via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Also, @srikanth-k mentioned this combination of keys in his answer.

Comment: Above is not what I'm after. Edited the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search in files: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and then choose tab `File Search`.

If you want to search for resources: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

If you want to search for Java types: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

If you want more shortcut keys: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Above is not what I'm after. Edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: You can still use the above combination keys to do the needful.@sampath